# MySQL - Select top 80 and bottom 20 rows in one query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have Database table called tbl_emails like this

```
    id   email

    1    example1@example.com
    2    example2@example.com
    3    example3@example.com
    4    example4@example.com
    5    example5@example.com
    6    example6@example.com
    7    example7@example.com
    8    example8@example.com
    9    example9@example.com
    10   example10@example.com
```

I have about 5000 rows in the table. Now What I am looking to do is get 100 emails from it. But I want **80 rows means 80% DESC and 20% ASC by id**, currently I am doing it by multiple queries and merging result in PHP. I am wondering its possible in single SQL query?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a row_number element and `order by case when rn <=80 then -rn else rn end` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UNION ALL](https://sql.sh/cours/union/union-all)to join the results of 2 queries with the same columns.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, email
    FROM tbl_emails
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 80
) AS top
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, email 
    FROM tbl_emails
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 20
) AS bottom;
```

If you need to preserve order of the rows in the ouput, you can in addition use variables to store the row count in each query

```sql
set @top := 0;
set @bottom := 0; 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, email, @top := @top+1 AS top, @bottom AS bottom
    FROM tbl_emails
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 80
) AS top
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, email, @top AS top, @bottom := @bottom + 1 AS bottom  
    FROM tbl_emails
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 20
) AS bottom
ORDER BY top, bottom;
```

Comment: No, this is not guaranteed to work and is incorrect; the ordering applied to a derived table is not guaranteed to be retained in the final select, the outer select *always* requires an ordering criteria to guarantee order.

Comment: @Stu In what case would that not work ?

Comment: in the case that it is a fundamental property of sets, in that sets (a table, a derived table, a table expression etc) have no inherent order; the ordering used in a derived table with *limit* serves only as part of the definition of which rows to return. Any assumptions made that ordering will be retained in a set without an order-by is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: And besides, if I understand OP correclty, what really matters is the filtering (get the first 80 and the last 20 lines) and not the order of the output.

Comment: That aspect is unclear from the OPs question.

Comment: This is working fine for me as My Requirements. I don't know who have voted it negative and why

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide a more complex query with the ability to preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76897343/1191247) has some unnecessary overheads/issues.

Firstly, using the derived tables requires two additional temporary tables. This is not the end of the world, but it is unnecessary.

Secondly, the introduction of the [deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-deprecation-removal) `Setting user variables within expressions` just guarantees an issue in the future when this functionality is removed.

```sql
(
    SELECT id, email, 0 AS s
    FROM tbl_emails
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 80
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT id, email, 1 AS s
    FROM tbl_emails
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY s ASC, IF(s = 0, id, NULL) ASC, IF(s = 1, id, NULL) DESC;
```

Further to Stu's comment about the need to order the outer select, [the docs state](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-operations.html#set-operations-order-by-limit:%7E:text=Use%20of%20ORDER%20BY%20for%20individual%20query%20blocks%20or%20statements%20implies%20nothing%20about%20the%20order%20in%20which%20the%20rows%20appear%20in%20the%20final%20result%20because%20the%20rows%20produced%20by%20a%20set%20operation%20are%20by%20default%20unordered.):

> Use of ORDER BY for individual query blocks or statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because the rows produced by a set operation are by default unordered.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3rG0iDiW)